# How to disable escaping URL/string in an HTML template in a javascript block

Tags: javascript, go, go-html-template

I've tried to render a url as string, URL, JS and HTML. In all the cases this:

```
 <script>
  var someUrl = "{{ .myUrl }}";
 </script>
```

gets rendered to this value:

```
https:\/\/some_domain123.com\/path1\/path2\/path3
```

No matter what.

I want this:

```
https://some_domain123.com/path1/path2/path3
```

What actually works?

Comment: Remove the double quotes from your html. ie `var someUrl = {{ .myUrl }}`.

Comment: The string `"https:\/\/some_domain123.com\/path1\/path2\/path3"` is equal to `"https://some_domain123.com/path1/path2/path3"` in Javascript.  The template adds the backslashes to protect against various attacks.  Why are the backslashes a problem in your application?

Comment: @ThunderCat why do you want to know why?

Comment: I am trying to understand if there's an actual problem to solve and what it is.   There's encoding of the URL works OK as is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`https:\/\/some_domain123.com\/path1\/path2\/path3` is the same as `https://some_domain123.com/path1/path2/path3` in JavaScript.

So, it actually works.

Answer (score 1):

As @mkopriva commented, remove the double quotes around `{{ .myURL }}`, and it works as you want.

[See it on the Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/8GEB33oKX-c)